# Wrapfigure not working

Tags: diagrams, wrapfigure, picture-mode

I can't figure out why the first code shows the picture in a totally different place, while the second one works just fine, any clue?

The one not working:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.5cm}
\begin{picture}(4,8)
\thicklines

\put(1,2){\line(1,0){4}}
\put(1,2){\line(0,1){4}}
\put(1,4){\line(1,0){1.5}}
\put(5,4){\line(-1,0){1.5}}
\put(5,2){\line(0,1){4}}
\put(1,6){\line(1,0){4}}

\put(2.7,3.8){$A$}
\put(0,2.6){$x_0$}
\put(5.4,2.6){$x_0$}
\put(0,5){$x_0$}
\put(5.4,5){$x_0$}
\put(2.7,6.4){$x_0$}
\put(2.7, 2.6){$F$}
\put(2.7, 5){$f$}
\put(2.7,1){$B$}
\end{picture}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

and the one working:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.75cm}
\begin{picture}(1,4)
\thicklines

\put(3,0){\line(1,0){4}}
\put(3,0){\line(0,1){4}}
\put(7,0){\line(0,1){4}}
\put(3,4){\line(1,0){4}}

\put(5,0){\line(0,1){1}}
\put(5,4){\line(0,-1){1}}
\put(3,0){\line(1,1){1}}
\put(7,4){\line(-1,-1){1}}
\put(3,4){\line(1,-1){1}}
\put(7,0){\line(-1,1){1}}
\put(3,2){\line(1,0){1}}
\put(7,2){\line(-1,0){1}}

\put(2.2,1.9){$x_0$}
\put(7.3,1.9){$x_0$}
\put(4.8,4.4){$x_0$}
\put(4.8,-0.7){$x_0$}

\put(4,1){\line(1,0){2}}
\put(4,1){\line(0,1){2}}
\put(6,1){\line(0,1){2}}
\put(4,3){\line(1,0){2}}

\put(4.1,1.9){$x_1$}
\put(5.4,1.9){$x_1$}
\put(4.8,2.6){$x_1$}
\put(4.8,1.2){$x_1$}
\put(4.8,1.8){$f$}

\end{picture}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

What I mean by the fact that it shows the picture in a different place is that even though the code is in a specific point of the text the picture shows up in a totally different place, that's quite bizarre.

Comment: One clue is found in the [wrapfig package documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig). A lower case 'r' as parameter 2 allows the figure to float (so its position might change). An upper case 'R' would prevent floating.

Comment: @IanThompson it looks like I'm not the only one experiencing this kind of weird behaviour, I found this comment on the documentation:
"It doesn't work more often than it does. You can experience all kinds of weird behavior. On my list are: cutting out empty windows on several pages; moving the figure 10 pages after the page it was inserted to; drawing the figure over the text without wrapping whatsoever,..."
Btw I tried using 'R' instead of 'r' and didn't work.

Comment: OK ... please edit your question so that it shows a complete example code that reproduces the problem. Without that any solution is guesswork (my r -> R suggestion was just the most obvious guess).

Comment: @IanThompson - Actually, it is the other way around: upper case floats and lower case doesn't.

Comment: The position of the wrapfig is totally unrelated to its content (apart from its height), it is influenced by the surrounding text and whether it is possible to make a cut-out so you have not shown any code related to your question. Please always post a complete small document that shows the problem, not disconnected fragments.

Comment: One easy  thing to remember is that `wrapfig` is incompatible with lists. `itemize` and `enumerate` are the obvious ones, but LaTeX defines quite a few other environments as lists and they're not always obvious.

Comment: @JohnKormylo --- oops, I misread the documentation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I actually used `wrapfig` in `itemize`, I think that's why is not working